# Categories Dropdown Box (edititem.aspx)

Tags: 2013, document-library, filter, categories

I would like users to be able to select a pre-determined category from a dorpdown list rather than manually typing in their own category. The image below shows the current 'New Item' screen in SharePoint, is it possible to replace the 'Category' text box with a drop down box displaying choices of category?

Thanks.

edit: I should also probably state, this is when a user is uploading a file to a Document Library.

[image: New Document]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to your document library and go into your document library settings, you should see your column Categories.

When you click on it you can change the type of the column to "Choice" and then you can define the choices the user should choose from and the way it is displayed (by default a dropdown)

Comment: Makes sense! I just replaced the default categories column with one with as 'Choice' works perfectly. Thanks for the help :).